# VS Code - Configuration Properties - presentation order

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185428/vs-code-extension-how-do-you-set-an-order-priority-to-the-extensions-settings) from ~ 3 years ago, and linked Github issues that appear to have been worked on and closed in the 1.63 build onwards, I cannot get my `package.json` order settings to make any difference to the displayed item order (currently on 1.64.2). Here's my file:

```json
{
    "name": "taxi-for-email-validator",
    "displayName": "Taxi for Email validator",
    "description": "Validate Email Design System syntax",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "SparkPost",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/tuck1s/taxitest.git"
    },
    "icon": "images/taxiforemail-white-on-blue.png",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.64.0"
    },
    "categories": [
        "Linters"
    ],
    "activationEvents": [
        "onCommand:taxitest.validateEDS"
    ],
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "taxitest.validateEDS",
                "title": "Taxi for Email - validate Email Design System syntax"
            }
        ],
        "configuration": [
            {
                "type": "object",
                "title": "Taxi for Email",
                "properties": {
                    "taxi.uri": {
                        "order": 1,
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "uri",
                        "default": "https://myaccount.emailcms.net",
                        "description": "Enter your account URI including your account subdomain. You can find this in the browser address bar when you are logged in to your account."
                    },
                    "taxi.apiKey": {
                        "order": 2,
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "abcdef",
                        "minLength": "1",
                        "description": "Enter an API Key from your account. When you are logged in to your account, create a key under Integrations / API Keys / Add new. Record this value safely."
                    },
                    "taxi.keyId": {
                        "order": 3,
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "ID_xyzzyabcd",
                        "minLength": "1",
                        "description": "Enter an API Key ID from your account. This is visible as you add a new key. Existing key IDs can be seen under Integrations / API Keys / Edit API Key."
                    },
                    "taxi.showSummary": {
                        "order": 4,
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "description": "Enables informational output of lines checked, errors, warnings, and run time"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
        "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
        "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/node": "14.x",
        "@types/vscode": "^1.63.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.0.3",
        "eslint": "^8.6.0",
        "glob": "^7.2.0",
        "mocha": "^9.1.3",
        "typescript": "^4.5.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.25.0",
        "form-data": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

[repo link](https://github.com/tuck1s/taxitest/blob/master/package.json).

it *still* shows in alphabetic order - see below.

[image: extension settings]
What am I doing wrong? I think I'm following the guidance given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration).

Does anyone have a known good `package.json` using ordering that I can compare with?

Comment: In the screenshot, have you used the search to filter for Taxi settings? Try clearing the search field and instead go to 'Taxi for Email' under 'Extensions' in the tree to the left.

Comment: Yes! That makes a difference - thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you want to file an issue that the order of settings should be respected also in searches.

Comment: Yes - done. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [fixed in 1.66.0 onwards](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/146156).